# SonarQube Scanner stuck during AST scan on one java file

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

Sonar Scanner is not able to finish scanning. I checked the logs and I saw that scan stuck on one file as below

> INFO: 977/6093 files analyzed, current file: C:\Projects\ABC\src\main\java.com.cmp.rpt.Report.java

The scanner keep printing this message and the scan never finishes.
This is a recent issue. I checked the history of that file and nothing has changed on that file. I recently updated the Java plugin in Sonar. 
My server configuration is as below

SonarQube Scanner 2.8 (Tried 2.9 as well with no success)

SonarQube java plugin version 4.6.0.8784

SonarQube server 5.6.5

Could anyone shed some light on this issue

**UPDATE**: I reverted the SonarQube java plugin back to 3.13.1 and Scanner was able to continue. So the problem is in the new java plugin 4.6.0.8784

Comment: Would you be able to share the  file logged ?  you can reach out to sonarqube@googlegroups.com (and delete this question) to get an answer and send it privately to one of the developer of SonarJava.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot share the java source file. Apart from the source file  what can I provide so that you guys can replicate the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just answering my question for clarity.

I kept testing different version that were released after I faced the issue and finally in the below update the issue was fixed.

Update of SonarQube Scanner to 3.0.1.733 and SonarJavaPlugin to 4.8.0.9441.jar resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
When I updated to sonar-java-plugin-4.11 version 
 and sonar-scanner.3.0 version, 
the issue was fixed.